# Stored Procedure Error Handling when parameter left out

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure here that executes fine, but my custom error messages aren't working when I leave out a parameter. Instead I am getting the default error message.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am using SQL Server 2012

So for instance when I call it

```
Exec sp_getClientTransactioninfo '2001-01-01'
```

Should be printing

```
'This is the error msg= To Date required. Please enter To Date'
```

But it isn't.

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_getClientTransactioninfo
@FromDate DATETIME,
@ToDate DATETIME,
@Active int

 AS
Set NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

 -- Variables to handle error msg
Declare @error int, @errorMessage varchar(200)
SET @error = 0;
SET @errorMessage = '';

IF (@FromDate IS NULL)
BEGIN
SET @error = -1
SET @errorMessage = 'From Date required. Please enter From date'
GOTO Final_Process
END

IF (@ToDate IS NULL)
BEGIN
SET @error = -1
SET @errorMessage = 'To Date required. Please enter To Date'
GOTO Final_Process
END

IF (@Active IS NULL)
BEGIN
SET @error = -1
SET @errorMessage = 'Active status required. Please enter active status'
GOTO Final_Process  
END

Select RestaurantID, ClientName as Client,  Mem_Name as Member, Mem_Address as Address,               Sum(AmountSpent) as 'Amount Spent',
--((membersamt)/totclientamt)*100
convert(varchar,floor(round((SUM(mv.AmountSpent)/ ( select SUM(AmountSpent) from         UDC_MemberVisits  umv where 
umv.RestaurantId=mv.RestaurantId )) 
* 100,0)))+'%' as perAmountSpent

from dbo.UDClub_Client as C
join dbo.UDC_MemberVisits as MV on MV.RestaurantId = C.ClientID
join dbo.UDC_Member as M on M.Mem_ID = MV.MemberID

where MV.DateVisited between @FromDate and @ToDate

group by ClientName, Mem_Name, Mem_ID, RestaurantID, Mem_Address
order by ClientName

--Error Handling

Declare @ErrorVar INT
SET @ErrorVar = @@ERROR
IF @@Error <> 0
Final_Process:
Print 'This is the error msg=' + @errorMessage
Print 'Error code =' + CAST(@error as NVARCHAR(8));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your procedure like this

```
Exec sp_getClientTransactioninfo '2001-01-01'
```

Then you are going to get an error saying that the procedure expects the missing parameter `@ToDate`. The missing parameter is not set as null, it is just not there so SQL server throws an error saying it was expecting the parameter before even executing your procedure.

You can get around this, by setting your parameters to null in the declaration of your procedure, like so:

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_getClientTransactioninfo
@FromDate DATETIME = null,
@ToDate DATETIME = null,
@Active int
```

So if you do not provide the parameter, it will default to null and then your error message with show.

You may also want to look into [`RAISEERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) rather then [`PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I also had to set @Active int = null as well